# Read embedded object from Excel sheet row by row

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using java 8 with apache poi  3.9 in my application.I have stuck up in reading object from an Excel sheet.
I have one Excel sheet which includes student information like name, address and attachment documents(pdf,ppt or images) attachment of an student. 
I would like to know the read embedded objects row wise.

Comment: Why are you using [a version of Apache POI that's almost 7 years old?!?](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.9) What happens when you upgrade to something vaguely recent?

Comment: @Gagravarr If I change latest POI means how to get all objects?